# Node child_process vs Heroku worker

Tags: node.js, multithreading, heroku, child-process, worker

Trying to get my mind around workers vs threads on Node and Heroku.  What happens when you call `exec` from within Node.js?

Is it correct to believe this runs on a separate thread, and does not block the main event loop?

```
    require('child_process').exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      // ... do stuff          
    });
```

If on Heroku, is there an advantage to moving this to a separate worker? E.g.

- If computational intensive, would child_process slow the main app?
- Do worker dynos get their own memory limit?
- Would an uncaught error (heaven forbid) not crash the main app if in a worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node, a child process is a real separate process on the CPU, which is a child of your parent process (your Node.js script). This article explains this in much more depth here: http://www.graemeboy.com/node-child-processes

What this means on Heroku, is that if you use `child_process` to spawn a new child process, your Heroku dyno will actually be able to do 'more' total CPU work, as it will be running your child process code (most likely) on a separate physical CPU (this is very dependent on a lot of factors in your application, however).

This can be a problem, however, because each Heroku dyno only has a limited amount of CPU and RAM resources.

So for instance, if your Dyno code (the web bit, not a separate Heroku worker) is doing CPU intensive stuff and using `child_process` a lot, you will use up all your CPU resources and your code will start to block / hang in Node.

A much better idea (although slightly more expensive on Heroku) is to put all worker / asynchronous code into a separate worker dyno, and use that EXCLUSIVELY for processing CPU intensive stuff. This ensures your main web dynos will always be fast and responsive, as much as possible.

I personally like to use a queueing service like [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to handle passing data between my web dynos and my worker dynos, as it's super fast an inexpensive, but you have lots of options.

Every dyno you create (web dynos and worker dynos) get their own resources, so each dyno gets it's own set amount of CPU and RAM. The types of dynos available, and their resource limits, and explained here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

In regards to error handling, if you don't catch an exception, it's tricky to say what will happen. It is, however, very possible that your entire Node app will crash (and then Heroku will just restart it). It really depends on your specific implementation of various things =/